# Create android aar that contains another android arr

Tags: android, aar

I've created an aar (`mine.aar`) that references another aar (`other.aar`).

I have the source code from both `aar` and both are kept locally (in the libs directory).

I only want to distribute `mine.aar` so whoever adds it to its project, only needs to add one local file because the code from `other.aar` would be "inside" of `mine.aar`

When I add `mine.aar` to a project I'm getting:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  /Users/kodiak/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cc11357a55d4d7c90e9854a3725b5e6d/res/layout/activity_item.xml:17: AAPT: error: attribute libappbarlayout_fitsystem (aka com.awproject:libitembarlayout_fitsystem) not found.
```

Where `layout/activity_item.xml` is a layout in `mine.aar` that references a custom view from `other.aar` and `libitembarlayout_fitsystem` is an attribute of this custom view.

So my question is:

- Is it possible to ship `mine.aar` with the code from `other.aar`?

Comment: Not as aar file. Use a maven repo.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti So, without maven, I would have to make available `mine.aar` and `other.aar` to whoever needs to implement `mine.aar` or, since I have the code from `other.aar` copy that code to inside `mine.aar`. Right?

Comment: Yes it is correct.